# Does the function change the sign infinitely many times?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$; $\mu$ denotes the Moebius function. Consider the sums
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{k^\epsilon}.
$$
Do they change the sign infinitely many times as $n\to\infty$? (like the Mertens function corresponding to $\epsilon=0$)

Comment: For $\epsilon > 0$ this converges to a non-zero value, so it cannot change sign infinitely often.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you so much. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I think he spoke too soon. This doesn't converge. Presumably that is why you have chosen $\epsilon < \tfrac{1}{2}$. (For $\epsilon > \tfrac{1}{2}$, we do expect it to converge. This is deeply connected to the Riemann Hypothesis).

Comment: For me it was also surprising, as I mentioned the case $n=0$. However, my knowledge in this area is poor, so I am really interested in the answer :)

Comment: @mixedmath: Any related results and ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Results for the case $\epsilon\ge\frac{1}{2}$ are also of interest.

Comment: @0-0 Oops sorry, mixedmath is 100% correct: it definitely is divergent for any $\epsilon < \tfrac12$.  I was thinking of a different $\pm 1$-valued function whose partial sums are well-behaved.

Answer (score 2):

One can prove that this changes sign infinitely often by the same method used to prove, say, that $\psi(x) - x$ changes sign infinitely often. A standard reference for this is chapter 15 of Montgomery and Vaughan.

Comment: yes. the method is to derivate an explicit formula for $m_\epsilon(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n) n^{-\epsilon}$ in term of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ (in the exact same way as for $\psi(x)$), and as these are all of non-zero imaginary part, $m_\epsilon(x)$ has to oscillate for $\epsilon < \sigma_0$ (the RH being $\sigma_0 = 1/2$)

Comment: if all the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ are simple it will be : $$m_\epsilon(x) = \sum_\rho \frac{x^{\rho-\epsilon}}{(\rho-\epsilon) \zeta'(\rho)}$$ where $\sum_\rho$ is over ALL the trivial and non-trivial zeros

Answer (score 1):

Titchmarsh* at p. 370 shows that convergence of $W(x)= \sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ for $\sigma > 1/2$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for the [truth of] the Riemann hypothesis.

Also, assuming RH, the sum converges to $1/\zeta(s)$ for every $\sigma > 1/2.$ For values of $\sigma$ for which the sum converges it must be possible to bound the sum in some neighborhood for sufficiently high $n,$ and so the sum would not change sign.

Also on RH, for $1/2<\sigma,$ Titchmarsh at 371-72 shows that
$M(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(x)=\Omega(x^{1/2})$ using exactly the same technique used by Schmidt to show that $\psi(x)-x=\Omega_\pm(x^{1/2}).$ This can't be extended to $W(x)$ (at least for this interval) if $W(x)$ doesn't change sign.

As for $0<\sigma<1/2,$ this [MO question/answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146056/on-the-convergence-of-dirichlet-series-over-the-mobius-mu-function) seems to cover it. As the comments note, $W(x)$ diverges here. There is a comment on the MO question that I think is both correct and nice. Assume $W(x)$ is convergent for $\sigma_o <1/2$ on $(0,1/2).$ Then the series will converge in the half-plane $\sigma_o<\sigma.$ But there is at least one zero of $\zeta(s)$ for $\sigma = 1/2$ which is a singularity of $W(x),$ contradicting the assumption.

*Titchmarsh, The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function